# Edit backend code while running .net project

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Just want to ask if there is any way to make some changes while running vb project `backend code`.

Sometimes, when I need to add a character I should stop whole project, and run it again.

Comment: Well the code needs to be compiled, however you can compile during runtime using reflection.

Comment: @Bauss `you can compile during runtime using reflection` - please explain

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.aspx

Comment: And if he wants here is some really old code I got that could be used as a reference: https://github.com/BaussProjects/ProjectXV3/tree/master/ProjectX_V3_Lib/ScriptEngine